# Positioning issue in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph that appears really far left in I.E but its fine in firefox and chrome, I have been trying to fix this for a while now but i cant seem to get it to display correctly in all browsers

Codepen : https://codepen.io/mikegr/pen/ggXdVG

HTML

```
<p  class = "info">Welcome to the programming part of my portfolio,<br>
here you can find a link to my github profile all of my programming work is.<br>
There is also a link to a bonus Snake game I created using JavaScript.<br>
the languages I am experienced in include html,css,javascript,php,mysql,java,python and c++</p>
```

CSS

```
.info{
clear:both;
position: fixed;
display:block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
top: 70%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
padding: 10px;
font-style: italic;
font-weight:   700;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
width: fit-content;
height: fit-content;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 50px;
width: -moz-max-content;   
width: -webkit-max-content; 
display: table;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's mainly because `fit-content` isn't supported in IE. http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width.

```css
.info {
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
        <p  class = "info">Welcome to the programming part of my portfolio,<br>
            here you can find a link to my github profile all of my programming work is.<br>
            There is also a link to a bonus Snake game I created using JavaScript.<br>
            the languages I am experienced in include html,css,javascript,php,mysql,java,python and c++</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include a browser style reset CSS in your header before your main CSS script. These types of scripts reset browser CSS styles to be uniform among different ones.

I can recommend
[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) but there are many out there!

Comment: never heard of this before so i will look int that thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the code given below. just copy and paste it as it is. I hope it will work fine.

    <html>
        <head>
            <style>

            .info{
                position: relative;
                display:block;
                top: 500px;
                margin: auto;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                text-align: center;
                color: black;
                font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
                padding: 10px;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight:   700;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
                width: 50%;
                width: fit-content;
                height: fit-content;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 50px;
                width: -moz-max-content;   
                width: -webkit-max-content;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class = "info">Welcome to the programming part of my portfolio,<br>
                here you can find a link to my github profile all of my programming work is.<br>
                There is also a link to a bonus Snake game I created using JavaScript.<br>
                the languages I am experienced in include html,css,javascript,php,mysql,java,python and c++
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```